# Restrict geocoder results to a country or city

Tags: google-geocoder, rails-geocoder

I've been using Ruby gem Geocoder version 1.3 to find coordinates of an address. 
I need to restrict all results to a certain city or at least country because I'm getting most of the geolocalizations wrong.

I'm using Google for the search.

I tried for example:

`Geocoder.search('Juan Cayetano Molina 450', params: { region: 'UY', components: 'country|UY'})`

but I still get results in a different country. I also tried in params sending in `location`, `country`, etc. but no luck either.

I don't want to concat the city name to the search term because I'm getting as result the center of the city which is not what I wanted.

Can someone help me? Seems so simple but I couldn't find any answer that worked for me.

Comment: Did you try `Geocoder.search("Juan Cayetano Molina 450", params: {countrycodes: "uy"})`?

Comment: I LOVE YOU. Can you write that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Geocoder.search("Juan Cayetano Molina 450", params: {countrycodes: "uy"})` instead.